# PHP Get unique ID from user computer

Tags: php, session, cookies, ip

I want get unique id from user computer

I use session , cookie , ip and ,,, but not work successfully

Can get serial number of motherboard or ... ?

Comment: of course you can get mac, serial number of motherboard, bloodgroup of the user, mastercard id, puk etc .... onlything you have to do, is ASK the user

Comment: PHP is purely serverside. You will only get what the users sends to you. Sadly there is no system to 100% verify a user (webadmins way of sight) the good side is the point of privacy related with this. So all in all: No you cant

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$mtime=microtime();

$arrmtime=explode(" ",$mtime);

$no=$arrmtime[0].$arrmtime[1];

?>
```

Comment: what happens when 2 requests hit the script at the same microsecond?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible as I know.

Try this:

```
session_start();    
echo session_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can retrieve server side if the user's IP adress. Note that is the IP adress that the user sends to you. You can't be sure that's his real IP adress.

To get an uniq ID, you can use the phpfunction  [`uniqid();`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_uniqid.asp)

Note that's this function isn't very acurate, so you can mix this with the retrived IP adress and a hash function. Then you can store this id in the php session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['uniq_id'] = $generated_id;
```

[`session_id();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) is unique at the time of user own this session. But you're not garented that :

- The user keep this session id.
- An other user own this id in the future

Answer (score 0):

No, You cant get mac id or any kind of identification number from users computer. Even most of the ISP uses dynamic IP address. Dynamic IP changes when you disconnect and reconnect your internet connection. PHP provides the only way to trace users computer using cookie. Hope it wil be helpful.